# cv2.VideoWriter issues

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, http-live-streaming

I'm looking to record a Twitch Livestream by feeding it the direct livestream url using `streamlink.streams(url)` (which returns a `.m3u8` url). With this, I have no problem reading the stream and even writing a few images from it, but when it comes to writing it as a video, I get errors.

P.S.: Yes, I know there's other options like Streamlink and yt-dwl, but I want to operate solely in python, not using CLI... which I believe those two are only dealing with (for recording).

Here's what I currently have:

```
if streamlink.streams(url):
    stream = streamlink.streams(url)['best']
    stream = str(stream).split(', ')
    stream = stream[1].strip("'")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
    gst_out = "appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=stream "
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_out, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, (1920, 1080))
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        out.write(frame)
```

For this code, I get this error msg:

```
[tls @ 0x1278a74f0] Error in the pull function.
```

And if I remove `gst_out` and feed `stream` instead as well as moving `cap` and `out` into the while loop like so:

```
if streamlink.streams(url):
    stream = streamlink.streams(url)['best']
    stream = str(stream).split(', ')
    stream = stream[1].strip("'")
    while True:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
        _, frame = cap.read()
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(stream, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, (1920, 1080))
        out.write(frame)
```

I get:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' is not supported with codec id 12 and format 'hls / Apple HTTP Live Streaming'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fist part uses GStreamer syntax, and OpenCV for Python is most likely not built with GStreamer.
The answer is going to be focused on the second part (also because I don't know GStreamer so well).

There are several issues:

- `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)` should be before the `while True` loop.
- `out = cv2.VideoWriter(stream, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, (1920, 1080))` should be before the `while True` loop.
- The first argument of `cv2.VideoWriter` should be MP4 file name, and not `stream`.
- For getting a valid output file, we have to execute `out.release()` after the loop, but the loop may never end.

---

- It is recommended to get frame size and rate of the input video, and set `VideoWriter` accordingly:

  ```
   width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
   height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
   fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

   video_file_name = 'output.mp4'

   out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))  # Open video file for writing
  ```
- It is recommended to break the loop if `ret` is `False`:

  ```
   ret, frame = cap.read()

   if not ret:
       break
  ```
- One option to end the recording is when user press `Esc` key.
  Break the loop if `cv2.waitKey(1) == 27`.
  `cv2.waitKey(1)` is going to work only after executing `cv2.imshow`.
  A simple solution is executing `cv2.imshow` every 30 frames (for example).

  ```
   if (frame_counter % 30 == 0):
       cv2.imshow('frame', frame)  # Show frame every 30 frames (for testing)

   if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # Press Esc for stop recording (cv2.waitKey is going to work only when cv2.imshow is used).
       break
  ```

---

Complete code sample:

```
from streamlink import Streamlink
import cv2

def stream_to_url(url, quality='best'):
    session = Streamlink()
    streams = session.streams(url)

    if streams:
        return streams[quality].to_url()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not locate your stream.')


url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/noraexplorer'  # Need to login to twitch.tv first (using the browser)...
quality='best'

stream_url = stream_to_url(url, quality)  # Get the video URL
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)  # Open video stream for capturing

# Get frame size and rate of the input video
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))


video_file_name = 'output.mp4'

out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))  # Open video file for writing


frame_counter = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if not ret:
        break

    if (frame_counter % 30 == 0):
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)  # Show frame every 30 frames (for testing)

    out.write(frame)  # Write frame to output.mp4

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # Press Esc for stop recording (cv2.waitKey is going to work only when cv2.imshow is used).
        break

    frame_counter += 1

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Testing the setup using **FFplay** and `subprocess` module:

```
from streamlink import Streamlink
import subprocess

def stream_to_url(url, quality='best'):
    session = Streamlink()
    streams = session.streams(url)

    if streams:
        return streams[quality].to_url()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not locate your stream.')


#url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/noraexplorer'  # Need to login to twitch.tv first (using the browser)...
url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/valorant'
quality='best'

stream_url = stream_to_url(url, quality)  # Get the video URL

subprocess.run(['ffplay', stream_url])
```

---

### Update:

Using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) for reading the video, and OpenCV for recording the video:

In cases where `cv2.VideoCapture` is not working, we may use FFmpeg CLI as sub-process.
ffmpeg-python module is Python binding for FFmpeg CLI.
Using ffmpeg-python is almost like using `subprocess` module, it used here mainly for simplifying the usage of FFprobe.

---

Using FFprobe for getting video frames resolution and framerate (without using OpenCV):

```
p = ffmpeg.probe(stream_url, select_streams='v');
width = p['streams'][0]['width']
height = p['streams'][0]['height']
r_frame_rate = p['streams'][0]['r_frame_rate']  # May return 60000/1001

if '/' in r_frame_rate:
    fps = float(r_frame_rate.split("/")[0]) / float(r_frame_rate.split("/")[1])  # Convert from 60000/1001 to 59.94
elif r_frame_rate != '0':
    fps = float(r_frame_rate)
else:
    fps = 30  # Used as default
```

Getting the framerate may be a bit of a challenge...

Note: `ffprobe` CLI should be in the execution path.

---

Start FFmpeg sub-process with `stdout` as pipe:

```
ffmpeg_process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(stream_url)
    .video
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)
```

Note: `ffmpeg` CLI should be in the execution path.

---

Reading a frame from the pipe, and convert it from bytes to NumPy array:

```
in_bytes = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(width*height*3)
frame = np.frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8).reshape([height, width, 3])
```

---

Closing FFmpeg sub-process:
Closing `stdout` pipe ends FFmpeg (with "broken pipe" error).

```
ffmpeg_process.stdout.close()
ffmpeg_process.wait()  # Wait for the sub-process to finish
```

---

Complete code sample:

```
from streamlink import Streamlink
import cv2
import numpy as np
import ffmpeg

def stream_to_url(url, quality='best'):
    session = Streamlink()
    streams = session.streams(url)

    if streams:
        return streams[quality].to_url()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not locate your stream.')


#url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/noraexplorer'  # Need to login to twitch.tv first (using the browser)...
url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/valorant'
quality='best'

stream_url = stream_to_url(url, quality)  # Get the video URL

#subprocess.run(['ffplay', stream_url])  # Use FFplay for testing

# Use FFprobe to get video frames resolution and framerate.
################################################################################
p = ffmpeg.probe(stream_url, select_streams='v');
width = p['streams'][0]['width']
height = p['streams'][0]['height']
r_frame_rate = p['streams'][0]['r_frame_rate']  # May return 60000/1001

if '/' in r_frame_rate:
    fps = float(r_frame_rate.split("/")[0]) / float(r_frame_rate.split("/")[1])  # Convert from 60000/1001 to 59.94
elif r_frame_rate != '0':
    fps = float(r_frame_rate)
else:
    fps = 30  # Used as default

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)  # Open video stream for capturing
#width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
#height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
#fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
################################################################################


# Use FFmpeg sub-process instead of using cv2.VideoCapture
################################################################################
ffmpeg_process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(stream_url, an=None)  # an=None applies -an argument (used for ignoring the input audio - it is not required, just more elegant).
    .video
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)
################################################################################


video_file_name = 'output.mp4'

out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))  # Open video file for writing


frame_counter = 0
while True:
    #ret, frame = cap.read()    
    in_bytes = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(width*height*3)  # Read raw video frame from stdout as bytes array.
    
    if len(in_bytes) < width*height*3:  #if not ret:
        break

    frame = np.frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8).reshape([height, width, 3])  # Convert bytes array to NumPy array.

    if (frame_counter % 30 == 0):
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)  # Show frame every 30 frames (for testing)

    out.write(frame)  # Write frame to output.mp4

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # Press Esc for stop recording (cv2.waitKey is going to work only when cv2.imshow is used).
        break

    frame_counter += 1

#cap.release()
ffmpeg_process.stdout.close()  # Close stdout pipe (it also closes FFmpeg).
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
ffmpeg_process.wait()  # Wait for the sub-process to finish
```

---

Note:
In case you care about the quality of the recorded video, using `cv2.VideoWriter` is not the best choice...

Comment: Your code returns an error: ```[tls @ 0x12533c1b0] Error in the pull function.``` ... Perhaps it is worth saying that I'm on MacOS. I think it might be an encoding error. It writes to the file but has no duration, nothing plays. @Roten

Comment: `https://www.twitch.tv/noraexplorer` stream is offline. Try other channel. Make sure you are logged on to twitch.tv. Make sure that you can watch the stream from your browser first.

Comment: I changed the stream, it's not that.

Comment: What is the URL? I want to test it

Comment: Please add the command `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` to the beginning of the script, and add the output to your question. It could be that your version of OpenCV (or FFmpeg `.so` file that comes with OpenCV) does not support HLS format.

Comment: python version: 3.9.5 |
opencv version: 4.5.4 |
ffmpeg latest version |
link: twitch.tv/valorant

Comment: I am using Windows 10, and it's working. I don't have a Mac to test it. Try executing the script as administrator (or sudo) (if there is such thing in Mac). Note: OpenCV uses a specific version of FFmpeg shared object (not FFmpeg CLI). You may try posting the information from `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`. Maybe I see something...

Comment: I updated my answer with `FFplay` and `subprocess` testing code. Please make sure that you can watch the video using that code.

Comment: It does work. Is it possible to use FFplay without CLI?

Comment: `subprocess.run()` executes FFplay CLI within Python. We can do the same thing with FFmpeg CLI (but you want to operate solely in Python, not using CLI)...

Comment: The problem with using CLI in python by way of ```os``` or ```subprocess``` modules is the difficulty that comes with trying to stop the recording when a condition is met. Process IDs have to be kept track of and so on... it's a shit show imo. That's why I try to not use subprocesses as much as i can. That's why I was wondering if it's possible to use ffplay without CLI. That's the whole point why I'm posting, because I've always been able to record using streamlink with subprocess but I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that uses `ffmpeg-python` for reading the video, and OpenCV for recording the video. It uses FFmpeg CLI (as sub-process), but only for grabbing the video.

Comment: I really appreciate all the time you've spent helping me. I thank you very much!